# R: readHTMLTable returns empty list

Tags: r, xml

I'm trying to import the data on this website, but it simply isn't working. It's a simple HTML table, and so should be amenable to the `readHTMLTable` function in XML. Please advise.

```
require(XML)
url = 'https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/electoral-college/allocation.html'
table = readHTMLTable(url,header = T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `rvest` package

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

read_html("https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/electoral-college/allocation.html") %>% # read the html page
  html_nodes("table") %>% # extract nodes which contain a table
  .[5] %>% # select the node which contains the relevant table
  html_table(trim = T) # extract the table
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The other package worked for the original poster but for some reason was throwing an error on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

# Read HTML library    
URL <- "https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/electoral-college/allocation.html"
lst <- readHTMLTable(getURL(URL))

# Remove NULL elements in lst
lst <- Filter(Negate(is.null), lst)
```

Upon inspection we see that the main table is element 4 in `lst`

```
df <- lst[[4]]
df
#                  State Number of Electoral Votes
#1               Alabama                         9
#2                Alaska                         3
#3               Arizona                        11
#4              Arkansas                         6
#5            California                        55
#6              Colorado                         9
#7           Connecticut                         7
#8              Delaware                         3
#9  District of Columbia                         3
#10              Florida                        29
#11              Georgia                        16
#12               Hawaii                         4
#13                Idaho                         4
#14             Illinois                        20
#15              Indiana                        11
#16                 Iowa                         6
#17               Kansas                         6
#18             Kentucky                         8
#19            Louisiana                         8
#20                Maine                         4
#21             Maryland                        10
#22        Massachusetts                        11
#23             Michigan                        16
#24            Minnesota                        10
#25          Mississippi                         6
#26             Missouri                        10
#27              Montana                         3
#28             Nebraska                         5
#29               Nevada                         6
#30        New Hampshire                         4
#31           New Jersey                        14
#32           New Mexico                         5
#33             New York                        29
#34       North Carolina                        15
#35         North Dakota                         3
#36                 Ohio                        18
#37             Oklahoma                         7
#38               Oregon                         7
#39         Pennsylvania                        20
#40         Rhode Island                         4
#41       South Carolina                         9
#42         South Dakota                         3
#43            Tennessee                        11
#44                Texas                        38
#45                 Utah                         6
#46              Vermont                         3
#47             Virginia                        13
#48           Washington                        12
#49        West Virginia                         5
#50            Wisconsin                        10
#51              Wyoming                         3
```

The reason why your approach does not work is because `url()` which gets called when using `readHTMLTable` with an URL can't download from https. So you need to use `RCurl` to download the file first.

Comment: I tried running the code on my PC and I got this: Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure. I don't have my firewall on. Is there some kind of setting I need to enable?

Comment: @ZhaochenHe No idea; your error is not reproducible. Are you running an older `RCurl` version? The code above works for `RCurl_1.95-4.11` and `XML_3.98-1.16`.